# how to read numbers and text from camera in android?

Tags: android

I'm working on android application and it should allow users to take photos using camera and the application reads the text and numbers in the photo.

I don't know where to start from android studio. is there any good suggestion on github that could help me???

thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Khalil, Now i got the same Requirement same as you.I just want to use your references and I also want to know the advantages and disadvantages of scanning and getting the text, numbers.Please help me ASAP. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Hi @Naveen I've used Tess-Two it worked, but if you have a piece of paper it will read everything... what I needed before to read only one part...

Comment: Sorry for late response, I got the new requirement in previous application so gap.For me it is not working Khalil.Help me please.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Exception: Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.wordpress.priyankvex.easyocrscanner-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libpngt.so"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As others said OpenCV or OCR is the way to go.
Google maintains one OCR library called as "Tesseract" (reminds me of Avengers :P).
To make the job little easier there is a fork of Tesseract called as [Tess-Two](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two/)

It combines some other useful tools like Leptonica (image processing library). Build instructions are given on the Readme file.

To get started you can check out very easy to use OCR library 
[Easy OCR Library Android](https://github.com/priyankvex/Easy-Ocr-Scanner-Android) which uses Tess-Two under the hood.

Again usage instructions are in the Readme file. It is already built so you don't need to build Tess-Two.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use OpenCV library. Its abbreviature is Open Computer Vision Library. It has a reputation similar to OpenGL. There must be articles about yor issue in which library is ised. It can be linked static or dynamic using runtime application called OpenCV Manager (available in Google Play). You can use it both in Java and C++ code. Hope, it helps

PS i have an own example of it use.
https://github.com/androidovshchik/ProhibitingSignDetector

Comment: Your positioning of OpenCV is fairly misleading. OpenCV is an open source project. OpenGL (as well as OpenCL, etc) is an API standard defined by an industry consortium. These are entirely different things, except for the similar sounding name.

Answer (score 1):

i could give suggest about how i would do that if i needed to .

first of all you need to photo the picture only black and white  .

then cheack the min black pixels in row that will define a letter .(you dont want any shadow to recognize as potential letter. 
try and learn progress (any camera have diffrent resulution so it need to be some % of the picture row pixels.)

after that evrey letter have diffrent shape so you need to do for loop 5 times in diffrent angel until you get to the third gap of black rows.

after that some huge switch and if to get to the right letter need to do big research about the gap inside the letter proportion. 
to have a little dataBase could help if you wanted to get more then one font . 
again i not sure its the right way but that what i would do.

have fun :)

Answer (score 1):

You may try to find some Optical Character Recognition (OCR) library for Java

Check [Java OCR](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaocr/), [tess-two](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two), [Aprise](http://asprise.com/royalty-free-library/java-ocr-api-overview.html). And explore stackoverflow searching other OCR solutions.

Implementing your own OCR lib may be very difficult so think is it really necessary for your task.